# What is the ideal way to pivot a specific type of data on the basis of multiple columns of a table using python pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
id name age consumer_id consumer_name  esc    esc_date
1   A   12    1AQJ        test1        None     NaT
2   B   18    1AQZ        test2        None     NaT
3   C   21    1ZQJ        test3        Yes   2020-04-16
```

I want to manipulate the data and have new rows wherever values of column esc and esc_dates are present and Not Null, id should remain same as shown below:

```
id name   age   consumer_id   consumer_name  esc    esc_date    
1   A     12      1AQJ          test1        None     NaT        
2   B     18      1AQZ          test2        None     NaT         
3   C     21      1ZQJ          test3        None     NaT      
3  None   None    None           None        Yes   2020-04-16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with filtered rows by missing ant not missing values (`~`), for another missing values assign them by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) or filter only necessary columns, like `df3`:

```
df['esc_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['esc_date'])

m = df['esc_date'].notna()
df1 = df[~m]
df2 = df[m].assign(esc_date=np.nan, esc=None)
df3 = df.loc[m, ['id','esc','esc_date']]


df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], sort=False).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   id name   age consumer_id consumer_name   esc   esc_date
0   1    A  12.0        1AQJ         test1  None        NaT
1   2    B  18.0        1AQZ         test2  None        NaT
2   3    C  21.0        1ZQJ         test3  None        NaT
3   3  NaN   NaN         NaN           NaN   Yes 2020-04-16
```